# The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.HtmlProvider' reported an error: The 'Value'='XXXX' part of the cookie is invalid

Tags: f#, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I'm using HtmlProvider to web scrape stock company news e.g. `https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/{STOCK_SYMBOL_HERE}/news-headlines` but I'm getting an error in this line of code

```
let [<Literal>] stockNewsUrl = "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/AAPL/news-headlines"
let news = new HtmlProvider<stockNewsUrl>()
```

There is squiggle on the second line and the error was `Error FS3033  The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.HtmlProvider' reported an error: Cannot read sample HTML from 'https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/AAPL/news-headlines': The 'Value'='AAPL,technology' part of the cookie is invalid.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an HTTP request to https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/AAPL/news-headlines, we are required to provide a [CookieContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookiecontainer?view=netframework-4.5). Since you are using the [FSharp.Data](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/index.html) library, I suggest to use its [HTTP Utilities](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html):

```
type Nasdaq = HtmlProvider<"/tmp.html">
let cc = CookieContainer ()
let data =
    Http.RequestString ("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/AAPL/news-headlines", cookieContainer = cc)
    |> Nasdaq.Parse
data.Tables.``Today's Market Activity``.Html
|> printfn "%A"
```

Of course you have to pre-download the page and save to `/tmp.html` first.

Small note: if we already have the HTML string (as in our case), we use `Nasdaq.Parse`; if we have a url, we use `Nasdaq.Load`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I haven't pre-downloaded yet the page but able to access the site is enough for me to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this fails because F# Data sends cookies in a format that the Nasdaq service does not like. An easy workaround is to download the page once to have a sample available at compile-time and then download the page at runtime using some other means.

```
type Nasdaq = HtmlProvider<"c:/temp/nasdaq.html">

let wc = new WebClient()
let downloaded = wc.DownloadString("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/AAPL/news-headlines")

let ns = Nasdaq.Load(downloaded)
```

This works, but there are two issues:

- The page dos not contain any tables/lists, so the `ns` value is not giving you nice static access to anything useful
- I get timeout exception when I try to download the data using `WebClient`, so perhaps that also does not work (but it might just be that I'm behind a proxy or something..)

Comment: Hi @Tomas Petricek, I also have a problem downloading data using WebClient. I don't think I'm behind a proxy.

Comment: UPDATE: I tested different site and I can download the content. But the first issue NOT having nice static access is a problem.

Comment: @marvs Yeah, the HTML provider works only on HTML files with nice tables or lists. If the web page does not have those, then there is no magic it can do, sadly.